# Architecture to run emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm looking for best architecture to run around 100+ android emulators.

Currently I run 20 emulators from 4 VM's (each VM's can run 5 emulators) but I want to run 100 emulators and I'm not sure Its the best idea to create 20 VM's.

What is my best alternatives?

One alternative that I think about is to create Android dockers but not sure If its the best idea.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You need for testing?

Comment: What limitations have you faced when trying to achieve that?

Comment: I need them to run parallel, at least 100 emulators, the "limitations" are that I don't think it's the best idea to create a lot of VMs for that so I looking for another solutions